# Exit infinite loop by quitting application

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript application in which I have a background task running in an infinite loop.

```
repeat while true
    -- do some tasks
    delay 0.5
end repeat
```

When I export and run the application, I am not able to quit it normally, instead I have to use the force quit. How am I able to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the infinite loop implement the `on idle` handler. It allows to consider the `quit` command.

```
on idle
    -- do some tasks
    return 1
end idle
```

However there is a restriction. The minimum interval is one second.